# remove any element of vector<std::function<...>> that bound to member function

Tags: c++, vector, c++11, bind, std-function

how to remove function that bound to member function of `this` object :

```
std::vector<std::function<void(int)>> callbacks;

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() {
        callbacks.push_back(
            std::bind(&MyClass::myFunc,this,std::placeholders::_1)
        );
    }
    ~MyClass() {
        auto it = std::remove_if( std::begin(callbacks),
                                  std::end(callbacks),
                                  [&](std::function<void(int)>& f) {
                return // <-- this is my question
                       //     true (remove) if f is bound to member function 
                       //     of this
        });
        callbacks.erase(it,std::end(callbacks));
    }
    void myFunc(int param){...}
};
```

Comment: @K-ballo did u meant "can't get that information back" ?

Comment: Yes, sorry... The _function_ is abstracted out by some kind of _type erasure_

Comment: It is advised to call (free) `begin` and `end` without qualification, to let ADL do it's job in case the container is not a standard compliant one with member `begin` and `end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't in the general case without a buttload of extra work. Type erasure clears this information from the object, and `std::function` does not expose this information directly.

Your specific example may only have one member function that could be the candidate to remove, but what about a class with 5 members that could be stored as callbacks? You'll need to test for all of them, and it's also possible to bind member functions using a lambda, which is pretty much undetectable.

Here's one solution if:

- all callbacks are registered from within `MyClass`
- the container is amended to store extra information
- you're willing to do all the extra bookkeeping

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::function<void(int)>, void*>> callbacks;

class MyClass{
  static unsigned const num_possible_callbacks = 2; // keep updated
  std::array<std::type_info const*, num_possible_callbacks> _infos;
  unsigned _next_info;

  // adds type_info and passes through
  template<class T>
  T const& add_info(T const& bound){
    if(_next_info == num_possible_callbacks)
      throw "oh shi...!"; // something went out of sync
    _infos[_next_info++] = &typeid(T);
    return bound;
  }
public:
  MyClass() : _next_info(0){
    using std::placeholders::_1;
    callbacks.push_back(std::make_pair(
        add_info(std::bind(&MyClass::myFunc, this, _1)),
        (void*)this));
    callbacks.push_back(std::make_pair(
        add_info([this](int i){ return myOtherFunc(i, 0.5); }),
        (void*)this));
  }

  ~MyClass(){
    using std::placeholders::_1;

    callbacks.erase(std::remove_if(callbacks.begin(), callbacks.end(),
        [&](std::pair<std::function<void(int)>, void*> const& p) -> bool{
          if(p.second != (void*)this)
            return false;
          auto const& f = p.first;
          for(unsigned i = 0; i < _infos.size(); ++i)
            if(_infos[i] == &f.target_type())
              return true;
          return false;
        }), callbacks.end());
  }

  void myFunc(int param){ /* ... */ }
  void myOtherFunc(int param1, double param2){ /* ... */ }
};
```

[Live example on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/sTLRD)

Comment: The type isn't completely erased; its `type_info` is available from `function::target_type()`. I don't think you can use that to do what the OP wants, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Mike: True, maybe you could parse the `type_info::name()` value, but since that is implementation specific, I don't think it'll do any good.

Comment: `std::function` absolutely _does_ expose the info, see my answer. You can access the target object, if you know its type.

Comment: @Jonathan: Well, not really. It exposes the target type, if you already know it, but it does not expose whether it is a bound member function. And if you already know the target type a `std::function` stores, what's the reason to ask again? It just does not make sense, really, and as such I find the downvote highly unjustified.

Comment: Is it not reasonable to think you might not know the type of any one particular `std::function` but know that an object with a given target type is in a list somewhere, you just don't know which element of the sequence it is? Oh wait, that's exactly what the question is about. You said "you cant" and my answer proves you can, so your answer is not useful.

Comment: @Jonathan: That is specifically for one member function, anything more generic is not possible. Also, you can "bind" a member function through a lamba. Detectable? No.

Comment: That's not what the OP's example showed. I answered the question as it was stated, with working code. "You can't" is wrong. Maybe if you edit your answer to say that in the _general_ case you can't, because it could be an anonymous closure type, or some other wrapper that isn't `std::bind` (e.g. `boost::bind`) etc. etc. then it would be more useful.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13125/discussion-between-xeo-and-jonathan-wakely)

Answer (score 4):

```
    typedef decltype(std::bind(&MyClass::myFunc,this,std::placeholders::_1)) bound_type;

    auto it = std::remove_if( std::begin(callbacks),
                              std::end(callbacks),
                              [](const std::function<void(int)>& f) {
          return f.target<bound_type>() != nullptr;
    });
```

The member function template `std::function::target<T>` returns a pointer to the target object if it is of type `T`, otherwise it returns null. So you just need to be able to name the type of the target object, which you can get from `decltype`. Pretty simple really :-)

N.B. that will remove *any* callbacks of that type, not only ones that have bound the `this` pointer for the specific object being destroyed. If you are trying to prevent invoking callbacks on an object after it has been destroyed and have no possible way to identify which elements of the vector refer to which objects, you could consider putting a shared_ptr in your class, then storing a weak_ptr to it in the callback, which can be used to detect if the object has been destroyed:

```
class MyClass
{
    struct NullDeleter { void operator()(void*) const { } };
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> sp;

    static void safe_invoke(void (MyClass::*f)(int), const std::weak_ptr<MyClass>& wp, int i)
    {
        if (std::shared_ptr<MyClass> safe_this = wp.lock())
            (safe_this.get()->*f)(i);
    }

public:
    MyClass() : sp(this, NullDeleter()) {
        callbacks.push_back(
            std::bind(safe_invoke, &MyClass::myFunc ,std::weak_ptr<MyClass>(sp),
                      std::placeholders::_1)
        );
    };
```

This wraps the call to the member function with the `invoke` function that converts the `weak_ptr` to a `shared_ptr` before calling the member function. If the object has been destroyed the `shared_ptr` will be empty, so the function does nothing.  This doesn't actually remove the callback when it becomes invalid, but does make it safe to call.

Comment: can we make the predicate works for any member function?, which is if I have `MyClass::myFunc1` and `MyClass::myFunc2` pushed to `callbacks` vector on constructor, then both functions are removed from the vector on `MyClass` destructor

Comment: @uray: No, they are different kinds of function pointers; you would need to remove each individually.

Comment: @uray, only if both member functions have the same type (because if they do then the call wrapper returned by `bind` would also have the same type, even if it wraps a different instance of the type).  If you know the types of all your class' member function then you could make the lambda expression check for all the possible types: `return f.target<bound_type1>() != nullptr && f.target<bound_type1>() != nullptr &&` etc

Answer (score 2):

I once needed to do something like this and I solved it by storing a vector of shared pointers of objects in the class that contain the function and remove the function from the vector by value when they are destroyed, which also makes this automatic.